Partitioned data - pushed down filter
I have data in ADLS which is partitioned as such:


The plan from the below query does not have the filter stage on the partition.

EXPLAIN ANALYZE select *
from read_parquet('abfss://<account>.dfs.core.windows.net/<container>/SkyCAST/FlightReportLevel1_1/**.parquet',hive_partitioning = true, union_by_name=true)
where ReportId=7031


How do I know for sure if the query is not doing a full scan of all the folders?
EXPLAIN ANALYZE select *
from read_parquet('abfss://<account>.dfs.core.windows.net/<container>/SkyCAST/FlightReportLevel1_1/**.parquet',hive_partitioning = true, union_by_name=true)
where ReportId=7031

The filter stage is not appearing in the plan produced.
